# Arduino light sensor

Tags: arduino

What other components do I need to add to make this circuit send values to analog pin on Arduino ? 
[image]

Comment: You just simply connect it at the question mark. Tho I don't really like how you connect the phototransistor at the top. And the BJT may affect the output. Best to use a mosfet here.

Comment: Yea you're Right it does affect the output. Should I try connecting it at the bottom?

Comment: You should. Just note that everything would be inverted so you'd use a PNP to drive the LED and have opposite values on the Arduino. Not too hard to change the code ^.^

Comment: I'll try that tomorrow. I'll let you know how it went

Comment: Also when using a PNP, you have to move the led to the other side as well.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the "5V" source going in to the phototransistor is truly no more than 5V, then you shouldn't need additional components to just get a reading. If it's the 5V pin from the Arduino itself, you'll be fine. Note that some power sources labeled "5V" may actually go higher than 5, in which case it may damage the Arduino.

The analog inputs are high impedance, so there is no need to worry about too much current going in to them.

That being said, as Bradman175 mentioned, the BJT may alter the analog pin's read value (slightly). Using a mosfet could help with that.

Comment: Yeah that 5v is supplied from Arduino ,when I connect that point where question mark is to analog input led goes high and basically phototransistor doesn't do anything. Led stays high no matter if it's bright or pitch dark in the room...

Comment: @ArturZ. - What if you disconnect the phototransistor, does the LED stay lit?

Comment: Yes it's fully on.

Comment: I forgot to mantion that on schematic both 5v is supplied from Arduino 5v

Comment: If you removed the phototransistor and the LED is still turning on, that means the Arduino's analog pin is leaking current into your circuit. But that shouldn't be happening. Perhaps the Arduino is damaged. Can you try using a different analog pin? If that doesn't work, a quick solution may be to add a diode at the analog pin to restrict current from leaking out, though that  will also affect readings a bit. Let me know if either of those help.

Comment: @ArturZ. - The diode would need to have the **-** side (with the stripe) facing the analog pin.

Comment: I just tried it. Both ways and 2 diodes going from voltage divider to diode and a1 and from voltage divider to diode and to resistor to transistor. Still same problem. I used 1n4148

Comment: @ArturZ. - I must be missing something. The only way that LED is going to turn on is if there is current supplied to the BJT's base pin. If the phototransistor is not connected, and the LED turns on when the "?" node is connected to the analog pin, that means the analog pin is supplying current to the BJT (which shouldn't be possible anyway). But if you used a diode, then the current should have been blocked. Perhaps your circuit doesn't quite match the schematic. I'm not sure. The current has to be coming from somewhere. Maybe you used a PNP BJT instead of an NPN?

Comment: I'll snap a picture of my breadboard tomorrow.

Comment: I tried today and it works fine using a2,a3,a4,a5. Doesn't work when it's connected to pin a0 or a1. Maybe because I'm using W5100 Ethernet shield .

Comment: @ArturZ. - Great, hopefully you're getting good readings too.